# color: inherit; does not work with ::selection in IE or EDGE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, selection

I have a page where the default text selection CSS is applied to set `background-color` to grey and the `color` to black.

Now, for a part of web page I want to preserve the `color` on text selection. I tried overriding the selection CSS for that part by using `color: inherit;`.
It worked for Chrome and Firefox but didn't work for IE and EDGE.

I have created a small example to  explain my problem:

```css
::selection {
  color: #000;
  background: #c6c6c6;
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: #000;
  background: #c6c6c6;
}
.p1 {
  color: red;
}
.p2 {
  color: green;
}
.override ::selection {
  color: inherit;
}
.override ::-moz-selection {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Heading 1</p>
  <div class="override">
    <p class="p1">Sub heading 1</p>
    <p class="p2">Sub heading 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to preserve `color` for the part of html with the class override and I can't change default selection CSS.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/h30jczkv/1/

Comment: Maybe IE doesn't support *inherit* in this case, why not using `.p1, .p1::selection{color:red;}` instead?

Comment: This is just a small example. Actually, there can be many such elements and I am not aware of color of each element.

Comment: @manpreetsingh Oye MP :)

Answer (score 2):

## This is not working because it is not supported in IE

IE does not support `inherit` when styling the `::selection` pseudo-element:

> Styling properties on the ::selection pseudo-element do not support the "inherit" value.

*::selection pseudo-element (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127349(v=vs.85).aspx)*

### You can do the following to get a similar result

The desired behaviour can be achieved without using `inherit` by using the `:not()` pseudo-class, although it will require some slight modifications to HTML. The principle behind this being that:

- You override the `background-color` for all elements with `::selection {background: #c6c6c6;}`
- Move the `override` class onto the `p` elements themselves
- You override the `color` for all elements except those with the class `.override` with `:not(.override)::selection{color: #000;}`
- *`.p0{color: blue;}` added to show that the change is working*

I don't think this behaviour can be obtained without modifying the HTML as the `:not()` pseudo-class only accepts [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

```css
::selection {
  background: #c6c6c6;
}
:not(.override)::selection {
  color: #000;
}
.p0 {
  color: blue;
}
.p1 {
  color: red;
}
.p2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="p0">Heading 1</p>
  <div class="override">
    <p class="p1 override">Sub heading 1</p>
    <p class="p2 override">Sub heading 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0f8wapsg/1/)**

### Alternatively, you could achieve this without modifying the HTML

*If* all the classes you want to override begin with `p` you could use the `[foo^="bar"]` attribute selector:

```css
::selection {
  background: #c6c6c6;
}
:not([class^=p])::selection {
  color: #000;
}
.t1 {
  color: blue;
}
.p1 {
  color: red;
}
.p2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="t1">Heading 1</p>
  <div class="override">
    <p class="p1">Sub heading 1</p>
    <p class="p2">Sub heading 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0f8wapsg/3/)**